permission denied to run mounted file docker-compose
I am trying to mount a volume in a docker-compose file, and run a bash file in the path.
But I get a Permission Denied error.
Here the docker-compose:
version: '3.8'

services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    volumes:
      - ./cmd/run_code.sh:/etc/cmd/run_code.sh:ro
      - ./conf/rabbitmq.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf:ro
      - ./conf/definitions.json:/etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json:ro
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    command: bash -c '/etc/cmd/run_code.sh'

Here the output I get:
rabbitmq_1  | bash: line 1: /etc/cmd/run_code.sh: Permission denied

I am running on an Azure VM with Ubuntu 22.04.
What am I doing wrong?
EDIT: edited docker to the correct version, with correct paths.

It seems that there's an issue with the mount path you're using. I don't see that exact permission error that you've reported but I do see one saying:

Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: '/home/projects/so-66767896/cmd/run_code.sh:ro:rw': invalid mount config for type "bind": invalid mount path: 'ro' mount path must be absolute

I'm also not sure where the path containing "/etc" is coming from. How are you running this config?
If I replace your relative mount with:
    volumes:
      - ./cmd/run_code.sh:/cmd/run_code.sh:ro


... and make the command use that path explicitly:
    command: bash -c '/cmd/run_code.sh'

The container runs my script (echo and exit) without issue.
Here's the modified config in its entirety:
version: '3.8'

services:
  rabbitmq:
    user: "${UID}:${GID}" # NOTE this addition
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    volumes:
      - ./cmd/run_code.sh:/cmd/run_code.sh:ro
      - ./conf/rabbitmq.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf:ro
      - ./conf/definitions.json:/etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json:ro
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    command: bash -c '/cmd/run_code.sh'

If that does not solve the issue, then the permission issue may be related to ownership of/access to the files you're mounting. Run the id command on your host machine and see what values are in use for "uid=" and "gid=". (They're probably along the lines of 1000 or 1001 -- I believe the actual value depends how many users are setup on your system.)
Copy those values into a file called .env alongside docker-compose.yml (create it if it doesn't exist):
UID=1000 # this may vary
GID=1000 # this may vary

Then try bringing your containers back up.
NOTE: You can also specify UID and GID on the CLI as env vars when running your compose commands, if you prefer: GID=2222 UID=2222 docker-compose up
Also, NOTE: You may be able to leverage the Z flag when mounting your files but I'm not able to test that at the moment. See: https://prefetch.net/blog/2017/09/30/using-docker-volumes-on-selinux-enabled-servers/

I corrected the docker-compose as you wrote (I copied the wrong version to the question). I still get the same error.

I tried the first solution, creating the .env file with the two values I found, but they don't seem to be overridden (if in the docker compose I try command: bash -c id I see uid=0,gid=0 instead of what I put in the .env file). Also running UID=1000 GID=1000 docker-compose up does not seem to override the values. Am I missing something else, perhaps in terms of permissions?

@GiacomoSachs Did you also add user: "${UID}:${GID}" to your RabbitMQ service definition?

I definently did not, I didn't try because I ended up changing the permissions to the file itself to 777 (and that solved). I'll try anyway the solution you proposed, and if it works I'll accept it. Thank you

The permissions on the file are not allowing the user/UID in the container to run this command.  This could be do to file level permissions or SELIUNX blocking issues.
Typically you would want to run these commands either in the Dockerfile or entrypoint.sh files ahead of time and build them into the image.
Without more details its hard to say which issue it is blocking you currently.
